# Why doesn't std::source_location provide lengths to avoid performance penalty in C++20?

Tags: c++, performance, std, c++20, standards

Consider the following code:

```
void Log(std::string_view       msg,
    std::source_location const& loc = std::source_location::current()) {
    
    // Performance penalty!
    auto const n = std::strlen(loc.file_name()); 
    auto s = ""s;
    s.resize(msg.size() + n);

    std::memcpy(&s[0], msg.data(), msg.size());
    std::memcpy(&s[msg.size()], loc.file_name(), n);

    // sendToRemoteMachine(s); 
}
```

Obviously, if `std::source_location::file_name` returns a `std::string_view`, the performance penalty can be easily avoided.

I think, `std::source_location::file_name` is a compile-time generated and readonly information. The compiler can store it into an `std::string_view` object.

Why doesn't `std::source_location` provide lengths to avoid performance penalty in C++20?

**Update**

Another related article: [`std::source_location` is Broken](https://www.elbeno.com/blog/?p=1738)

Comment: Why don't you use `std::format`? Why are you using the `std::puts` function?

Comment: This is just an example to illustrate the issue. `std::puts` is not the key to the problem. I rephrased the original code.

Comment: Not easily. `std::string_view` is not required to be null-terminated. If you need a null-terminated string, you'll have to make a copy.

Comment: I'm trying to imagine a use of source_location where copying it to an std::string is a big performance problem and failing.

Comment: The key to the problem is that `std::strlen` is slow. If we know the file name's length, the call to `std::strlen` can be avoided.

Comment: Could it be that under existing implementations, returning a string view *is* the performance penalty? A compiler likely exposes a null terminated string, and finding the end is unavoidable for string_view. Perhaps it's just more of "don't pay for what you don't use".

Comment: @Evg: Since the contents of those strings are governed by the standard, the standard can require that the pointer points to an array of characters one character larger than `string_view`'s range and that this last character is a NUL character. But yes, such an interface wouldn't make it explicit that it is a NTBS.

Comment: @xmllmx: "*The key to the problem is that std::strlen is slow.*" Is this a problem in *actual* code, or is it a thing where you go "technically I shouldn't have to compute it, but it wouldn't make a meaningful difference in my application's performance".

Comment: @NicolBolas, `file_name` is a compile-time information, the compiler can provide it as `constexpr std::string_view`, so, when we use `file_name` to build a more complex string, `std::strlen` can be avoided. The time complexity is from O(N) to O(1).

Comment: @xmllmx: My point is this: does it actually *matter*? Is this a theoretical concern, or do you have actual code whose real performance is being impacted by this? You can point at time complexity all you want, but if it doesn't make your program meaningfully slower, then who cares?

Comment: @NicolBolas The philosophy of C++ is: You don't pay for what you don't use.

Comment: @xmllmx: And yet, I can cite dozens of places in the standard where you do pay for what you don't need. Every time you create a `std::string`, you are also paying for a NUL-terminator even if you don't use any APIs that expect NTBSs. It is an aspirational aphorism.

Comment: @xmllmx: BTW, your example code now makes no sense. `std::string` strings are *always* NUL-terminated; adding a NUL-terminator manually makes no sense. If you're making a `std::string` from a `char const*`, just do that; it'll do the `strlen` equivalent internally.

Comment: @NicolBolas https://www.elbeno.com/blog/?p=1738 seems to agree with me.

Comment: @xmllmx: That argues for a radically different approach to `source_location`. Not just using `string_view`, but storing strings as types instead of values. `source_location`, even returning `string_view`, is not a `constexpr` object because `constexpr` parameters don't exist. So you can't turn them into types.

Comment: @NicolBolas `std::string_view` is just one of all possible types, just for illustration.

Comment: @xmllmx: ... so what? The problem pointed out in the article can only be solved by having `constexpr` parameters. What gets returned by `source_location::line` can only matter if it is a `constexpr` object. Which it isn't and cannot be because parameters are not constant expressions.

Comment: If you are looking for an alternate solution, you can use this: https://godbolt.org/z/KboGfYr5W

Comment: @xmllmx It does not agree with you. Having `file_name()` return a `string_view` would not address Ben's problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ does not have a type that represents all of the following:

1. Non-ownership of a string.
2. Has a known length.
3. Is NUL-terminated.

`std::string` has both 2 and 3, but not 1. `string_view` has 1 and 2, but does not guarantee 3 at the type level. `char const*` has 1 and there's a general expectation that they use 3, but they don't carry 2.

And yes, #3 is actually quite important. Your example wants to pass the string to an API that needs a sized string; that's why you're computing the size. Other people will have APIs that expect an NTBS. For them, a `string_view`-based API now requires that they copy the sized-string into an NTBS. Which is an O(N) operation.

Unless you have a type that communicates all 3 of these, one of you is going to have to do an O(N) operation.

Yes, technically, a `string_view` *could* point to an NTBS. But at the type level, if you're handed a `string_view`, you don't *know* that it points to an NTBS. That would be a guarantee from the function that generates it, not from the type itself. So it would be an inappropriate use of the type.

---

> Another related article

This article is about a largely separate issue: the lack of a `constexpr` version of `source_location`, one which would allow the string to be guaranteed to only exist at compile-time.

This issue is not something that any library construct could ever solve. Returning `string_view` from member functions wouldn't fix the problem from that article. While `string_view` can be `constexpr`, *parameters* cannot. And since `source_location` is passed as a parameter, it must follow the rules of the C++ language. Even though the compiler generated it, it is a parameter of the function and therefore it cannot be a `constexpr` parameter.

Indeed, it couldn't even be a C++ language construct because the language *cannot* pass compile-time information as a function parameter. Remember: the source of the information is the caller. What the writer of that article would do with `__FILE__` is manually stick it into a template parameter of that function, not a function parameter.

And it should be noted: returning a size isn't the problem as outlined by the article. You can compute a size of a `char const*` at compile-time, if the `char const*` itself is `constexpr`. You can then use that compile-time size and the `char const*` itself to manufacture a type. The problem the article is talking about is *entirely* in the scope of getting a compile-time sequence of characters. Whether it's a `string_view` or a `char const*` NTBS or a `char[N]` is irrelevant; any of them would work.

Comment: If we still use `__FILE__`, then `std::strlen` can be avoided. Why does `std::source_location` not provide length as the compiler knows that? What's the rationale behind?

Comment: @xmllmx: ... did you read the answer? `__FILE__` exists outside of the language. `source_location` has to follow the language's rules.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/line `__FILE__` seems to be of the C++ standard.

Comment: @xmllmx: It's not part of the *language*; it's part of the preprocessor. It isn't real C++. `__FILE__` is a preprocessor token that generates a string literal (which is a real C++ grammatical construct). `source_location` has to follow the rules of the language. It is a C++ type and therefore has to act like one. Its functions are member functions and have to act like them.